# C# inheritance and the "this" keyword

Tags: c#, inheritance, overloading

I am working on some code that was previously written by another developer, and I came across the block of code below:

```
/// <summary>
/// Default Constructor.
/// </summary>
public Body(Revision parent)
{
  mContainer = parent;
  mSections = new ArrayList();
  mSummary = new ArrayList();
}

/// <summary>
/// Constructs a Body from specified ParseElement.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="parent">Revision container.</param>
/// <param name="elem">Source ParseElement.</param>
public Body(Revision parent, ParseElement elem) : this(parent)
{more constructing stuff}
```

From what I understand, is that the overloaded constructor would also call the default constructor with the Revision that I send in, causing the initialized ArrayLists to be accessible from the overloaded constructor. Is this correct, or am I totally confused?

Comment: I wouldn't rely too much on the XML documentation in that code.

Comment: I know... the entire thing is horrible.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes, that is correct.  However, to correct your terminology:

- There is no "default constructor" except possibly the parameterless constructor, which doesn't appear to exist on this class.
- This has nothing whatsoever to do with inheritance.  This technique is actually called constructor chaining.

Comment: Also note that the `base` keyword can be used to perform constructor chaining; the difference being that it is used to invoke a constructor in a *base* class, whereas the `this` keyword is used here to invoke a constructor that is declared in *this* class.  Also note that specifying neither the `this` keyword nor the `base` keyword is effectively the same as specifying ` : base()`, unless your class does not derive from any base class.  If the base class does not define a parameterless constructor, then you will be required to explicitly specify a constructor with the `base` keyword.

Comment: @DWA: Except that everything derives from some class, even if it's the implicit superclass `System.Object`.  So it would be correct to say that `: base()` is always implicit. ;)

Comment: Ha ha, good point!  Although Eric Lippert might disagree with the technical correctness of that statement (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2009/08/06/not-everything-derives-from-object.aspx), for our purposes (defining classes) you are correct.

Comment: Ah, true.  Substitute "user-defined types" for "everything" in my comment.  :)

Answer (score 4):

This is correct and the technique is called constructor chaining.  In this scenario the `this` call can be loosely visualized as saying

> Run the specified constructor before the current constructor

They both run against the same object instance so changes in the called on are visible in the original.